# How to send logs to table so that we can view them in Workbench?

Tags: mysql

At log tab, it shows :

> ```
>                       Your current Log Destination is set to FILE.
>  For logs to be viewed within Workbench they must be configured to be sent to TABLE.
>              This option is only available in MySQL version 5.1 and newer.
>   Fore more information read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/log­tables.html
> ```

I am new to MYSQL and currently work with Workbench. I need to view query logs. Can you please show me step by step clearly how to make the log tab show query logs?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to not use table logs, as they have a non insignificant impact on system performance. This is because MySQL will write to the log tables for every single query and the performance hit is greater if your DB is busier, exact the opposite of what you normally want.

It shouldn't be too difficult to read the log *files* in a terminal window instead.

Should you really want to use Workbench for this, please  refer to the documentation ([updated link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html)) and try to follow it and if you have a problem with this, come back with a specific question.

Comment: I enabled genaral-log in workbench but now I don't know which file contains logs ?

Comment: The location is system specific. What platform are you on?

Comment: Window 7. I connected to Server Administrator then in configuration -> option files -> log files I ticked on general-logs.

Comment: Is your MySQL server on Windows 7 as well or is just the Workbench running there?

Comment: Both MySQL server and workbench are installed on Windows 7. I am running local host.